# Assigning xml structured output from webservice method in python

Tags: python, xml, suds

I'm calling a method called getNewReports() of a webservice. This method takes in a username and password and outputs xml structured data.

How can I assign this xml output to a variable in python. If I just do:

```
 reportxml = client.service.GetNewReports(username=user,password=pw)
 print reportxml
```

It's printing this: 
     (ArrayOfString){
           string[] =  abcd,efgh 
      }

I need the information in the string array. How can I create a separate array of values using the data from the String[] array ? Or how can assign an xml type variable to the output so I can parse the whole thing as an xml file?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datatype you recieve from calling `GetNewReports` is an `ArrayOfString`. The problem is, I don't know what methods this type supports.
Call `help(reportxml)` or `print dir(reportxml)` to see a list of it's methods and attributes or take a look into the `client.service` documentation (if any) to get information about this type and watch out for a way to extract the information it contains.

Hint: Actually in every languange, an array-like datatype supports indexing using `[index]`.

Comment: print dir(reportxml) gave me this: 
['__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__getitem__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__keylist__', '__len__', '__metadata__', '__module__', '__printer__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__str__', '__unicode__', 'string']

How do I use these methods though? when I did __str__(reportxml), it gave me an error.

Comment: nevermind that, it was very noobish of me. I guess I have to do str(reportxml) which converted the result to a string...but it still doesn't solve my parsing problem. I only need the elements in the String array.

Comment: `__str__`, `__getitem__` etc. are special methods. You should read some starter tutorials. `str(x)` invokes `x.__str__()`, `x[0]` invokes `x.__getitem__(0)`. try: `for e in reportxml: print e`.